# Blockdata Command not working with scoreboard (Minecraft 1.10)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using the following command:

```
    /blockdata 290 57 -436 
{Text1:"{\"text\":\"Cursor\",\"bold\":\"true\",\"color\":\"dark_green\"}",
Text2:"{\"score\":{\"name\":\"@p\",\"objective\":\"CursorPrice\"},\"color\":\"dark_blue\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/setblock 290 56 -431 redstone_block 0\"}}",
Text3:"{\"score\":{\"name\":\"@p\",\"objective\":\"CursorAdd\"},\"color\":\"red\"}",
Text4:"{\"score\":{\"name\":\"@p\",\"objective\":\"CursorAmt\"}}"}
```

and the sign that is being updated only shows the first line, and all of the objectives have values. The command block says it was updated successfully, even though all the lines except line one are empty. Note: the clickEvent also works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command works in 1.9.2 and below:

[image: Command working]

The problem you are having is caused by bug [[MC-101457]](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-101457) in 1.9.3 and later. Unfortunately, the solution is to wait for Mojang to get around to fixing it.

In the meantime, scores in `/tellraw` still work, so as an alternative, you could potentially have right-clicking the sign give the scores in chat.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response. It's good to know that the command works, at least in 1.9.2, so it's not on my part that the command is not working.